# FetchType.LAZY is not working for @manyToMany in Spring data jpa

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 3 entities *University,Student* and *Subject*. *University* and *Student* has a many to many relation and *Student* and *Subject* has also many to many relation. They are implemented as below.
**University:**

```
 @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinTable(
            name="UNIV_TO_STD_REL"
            , joinColumns={
                @JoinColumn(name="UNIV_DBKY", referencedColumnName="UNIV_DBKY")
                }
            , inverseJoinColumns={
                @JoinColumn(name="STD_DBKY", referencedColumnName="STD_DBKY")
                }
            )
        private List<Student> students;<br>
```

**Student:**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="students")
    private List<University> universities;
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name="STD_TO_SUB_REL"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="STD_DBKY", referencedColumnName="STD_DBKY")
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="SUB_DBKY", referencedColumnName="SUB_DBKY")
            }
        )
    private List<Subject> subjects;<br>
```

**Subject:**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="subjects")
    private List<Student> students;
```

Now, I want to get students for a particular University.But not the related subjects. So, I'm calling repository as below:

```
University u=UniversityRepo.findByUnivId("1234");
u.getStudents();
```

But, this is returning me the list of students along with related subjects from Subject also.It seems that while I'm calling *u.getStudents()*, it's not only fetching students, also fetching the subjects, though the *FetchType is LAZY*.
Please suggest.

**EDIT:**
UniversityRepo

```
public interface UniversityRepo extends JpaRepository<University, BigInteger> {

    public University findByUnivId(String id);
}
```

Comment: Can you Show the implementation of `UniversityRepo.findByUnivId` How are you determining that subject is loaded? Keep in mind, that if you inspect the value in the Debugger, (`Student.getSubjects())` it will Trigger Lazy loading as well. So, check the queries on the console (enable Output) at which time subjects are really loaded.

Comment: I can see subjects has been loaded while calling _u.getStudents()_.In debug mode, I can see there is a select for _University u=UniversityRepo.findByUnivId("1234")_ and 2 consecutive select query in the next step i.e. _u.getStudents()_. Thanks!

Comment: Ofcourse you see them in debug mode as that triggers the loading... As soon as you check the collection it will be retrieved.

Comment: as @M.Deinum underlines, try to do `u.getStudents().get(0).getName()`

Comment: @M.Deinum In that case, FetchType.LAZY is not in use. right? I was expecting to load students collection only, not the related subjects collection.

Comment: If you look at the students, your debugger is checking the fields to get them to display, which in turn triggers the loading.

Comment: Is there any way to stop the loading of subjects?

Comment: @Babun No, cause that's how it should be: Load it if it is accessed. To verify it's lazy loaded by the Debugger, you could enable the query Output, set a breakpoint right after "getStudents()". You should now NOT see any query about subject. As soon as you start to inspect (in debug mode) the subject collection, you should see the queries beeing fired. If it is like this, LazyLoading is working correctly. If Subject is loaded "right away", you might have a Piece of code somewhere, accessing the subject after a Student has been loaded.

Comment: Got it. Just wondering, in that case if there is further joining with table _Subject_, it will load all the data down the line! Btw, thanks all! for your responses.

Comment: see this：
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727017/configure-jackson-to-omit-lazy-loading-attributes-in-springboot

Answer (score 0):

You may be using springboot's default LocalEntityManagerFactory which is shipped along spring data in spring-orm package. This FactoryBean has limited configuration power and is recommended for standalone applications which solely use JPA for data access. Consider using the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean if you want to set up your persistence provider for an external DataSource and/or for global transactions which span multiple resources, or deploy it into a full Java EE application server and access the deployed EntityManagerFactory via JNDI.
Here I leave 2 important links for better documentation: [Spring JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch13s05.html), [LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html)